# apache2 cannot be restarted :Action 'start' failed

Tags: linux, apache2

I have a linux server that contains many websites under vhosts, once I deleted an alt site the apache2 coud not be restarted indecating this message in the error log:

```
  #eror log
(2)No such file or directory: apache2: could not open error log file /var/www/vhosts/deleted_Site/logs/error.log.
Unable to open logs
```

How can I stop that so I can start my apache2

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your apache configuration, for instance in conf.d/, all configuration related to your old website, especially for error logs (look for access logs and errors logs directives specification, somewhere in your conf files, apache2.conf, httpd.conf, sites-enabled, mods or what/wherever it is).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, you need to stop other process using same port. In some of cases it is nginx. you can stop it

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop

Answer (score 0):

Turn off any servers using the same port. For example to turn off `nginx` try this:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).